# How to tune memory usage of Gradle Daemon, when started by Intellij IDEA

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, memory-management, ram

I can tune the memory usage of my Gradle Daemon using this environment variable:

```
export GRADLE_OPTS="-Xms32m -Xmx64m -server -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs='-Xms128m -Xmx512m'"
```

I put this on my ~/.bashrc and works. My daemon is not eating more than 512m, because of the -Xmx512m above.

The problem is that when I run unit tests (or other operations that needs Gradle) using IntelliJ, the Daemon is configured to go to -Xmx1024, ignoring my setting.

So, how can I config this on IDEA?

Note: I put also this env variable on gradle run configuration, and it's ignored.

Comment: For me (using IntelliJ 2020.1.2), IntelliJ spawns a Gradle daemon with the JVM parameters that I specified in a `gradle.properties`. I double-checked by connecting Java Mission Control to the Java process running the daemon. Are you sure you don't have something similar in your build? (Default for recent versions of Gradle is already 512mb btw.)

Comment: So I guess that is the answer then - move the configuration to `gradle.properties` instead of having them in `.bashrc`. It should be on the form `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms128m -Xmx512m` (without quotes or the `-D` part) and the rest can be dropped.

Answer (score 0):

As my IntelliJ 2022.2.3 uses the gradle wrapper, it is only working when I put the config into the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file like so:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms64m -Xmx256m
```

Of course the required memory depends on the project we try to build.